# Rgd Window Batch File Command

Tags: shell, batch-file, window

Below is my batch code

```
:START
echo RUNNING START
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.google.com
ping -n 30 127.0.0.1 > nul
echo RUNNING DONE 30 secs
taskkill /im chrome.exe
echo KILL CHROME
GOTO START
```

I trying to lets say run google.com every 30 seconds using my window batch file and load it at window cmd prompt by

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>cd Desktop

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>chrome.bat
```

But problem is on the part where it load line 3

which is

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.google.com
```

The command prompt will stuck and hang, and not execute the next line.

**What i want to achieve is**

LOOP every 30 seconds, loading a specific page e.g google.com

I not ddosing Google.com or what, I Just actually want setup a simple cron job to load 1 of my page every 30 seconds using google as example in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.google.com
instead of 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.google.com
```

this will start a new processes and let your batch continue.
and

```
taskkill /F /im chrome.exe
```

It works either cases for me.

Comment: when I type start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://www.google.com , my chrome did not execute . nothing happen

Comment: I tried with IE. Can you use that browser ? If chrome does not start - maybe it is not located to that path or is broken (though little chanses..

Comment: What does it display is you type "start notepad" in cmd ?

Comment: Should work http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Windows_Server_2008_R2_Command-line_Tools

Comment: Try it now - it requires leading quotes for the title when another term is quoted, in most cases.